# Is there a verb form for 'Logistics'?

Tags: verbs, parts-of-speech

Is there a verb form for 'Logistics'?

> We logistic your growth.

Does this sentence make sense in English?

Comment: Have you found any other instances of 'logistic' being used as a verb?

Comment: [Grammarphobia](http://www.grammarphobia.com/blog/2014/05/logisticate.html) has: _The M-W Open Dictionary also has a July 1, 2006, entry from an anonymous contributor for “logisticize,” which is defined as “To organize the logistics of (an occasion). To plan (as a trip, party, or major event).”

The entry includes this example: “We have so many events to logisticize this year that my siblings with the planning gene will be in ecstasy.”_ But whether or not an 'Open Dictionary' can be considered a valid authority is doubtful. Urban Dictionary also has 'logisticize', but again ...

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - Certainly, that covers 'logisticize' (what a frightful word!). But the questioner (whom I was hoping to encourage into doing some of his own legwork) asks about the verb 'logistic'...

Comment: @EdwinAshworth -ize being the productive suffix that it is and _Logistics_ in the sense of _organization of supplies etc_ being French in origin I don't see why _logisticize_ would be a bad choice, better than _logisticate_. It has some previous back to the 19th century (not a lot I'll admit).

Comment: I've been Erikized.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - And at no charge!  :)

Comment: The word *logistics*, which has been used in English since the late 19th century, is from the French *logistique*, which derives from the verb *loger*, 'to lodge'. I submit this for information only. It seems a long journey from *lodge* to *logisticise*.

Answer (score 5):

As suggested in the comments above, logistic is not a verb, and *[logisticize  or logisticate](http://www.grammarphobia.com/blog/2014/05/logisticate.html)* may sound queer and are definitely unusual:

Logistic refers to [logistics](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/heedless) meaning:

> - (Economics) the management of materials flow through an organization, from raw materials through to finished goods
> - the detailed planning and organization of any large complex operation.

I think that [coordinate](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/coordinate) may well fit in your sentence suggesting the management of planning and organisation of operations.

Answer (score 0):

Grammatically this sentence does not make sense. *Logistic* is an adjective. Its describing the application of logic to a complex problem or the shape of a [curve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function). Logistic growth curves are used to describe populations of organisms that initially grow rapidly and then plateau at some upper limit.

Comment: Logistics also has other meanings. For example, what does a logistics company do?

Comment: Point well taken. A logistics company applies logic to complex problems. In any case, logistic still an adjective. In my world logistic and growth have a predefined association. I will update my answer accordingly.